# GDB immediately exits back to terminal after run command (even with breakpoints set)

Tags: c, debugging, unix, gdb

Program compiled with

```
gcc -g -o DynamicData main.o list.o
```

and opened in GDB as

```
gdb DynamicData
```

doesn't seem to work. As soon as I type run, GDB just returns to my main terminal. Even when I set breakpoints it just exits. There's no error, which is the weird part, and I haven't been able to find anything online.

Really need to find where the coredump is happening in my code (it's due in a few days!) so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Running on a SunOS 5.10 machine if that helps

Comment: There's no Solaris 5, as [far as I know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29)

Comment: Maybe you mean SunOS 5.10; but that would be over 10 years old

Comment: Working on a SunOS 5.10 machine would only make sense if you're using it to run a mission-critical piece of software in a long-time stable environment. But seeing that you're just learning C (your other question), I doubt you should be using it. Just boot any other Unixoid operating system, and see whether gdb behaves better there.

Comment: Pretty sure it's SunOS 5.10, we're required to ssh into the schools computers to do all of our assignments

Comment: If you type `start` instead of `run`, does it still cause gdb to exit?

Comment: What version of gdb are you running?

Comment: GDB 7.4.1 and when I use start instead of run, it tells me where I put a breakpoint, then returns to the shell prompt.

Comment: @zaya: if you have a machine that can SSH into another machine, why on earth aren't you developing and debugging your program locally?

Comment: That's a good point, I'm not sure why I didn't think of that.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> As soon as I type run, GDB just returns to my main terminal.

Please be more precise. There are two ways your statement can be interpreted:

1. As soon as you type `run`, you are returned to the `(gdb)` prompt.
2. As soon as you type `run`, GDB exits and returns you to the shell prompt.

In either case, it appears that GDB is broken on your machine (but exactly how it's broken and why would differ between the two cases).

You could try to use the Solaris system debugger `dbx`, which is less likely to be broken, or talk to your system administrator to get GDB installation fixed.

Comment: The second case, GDB exits and I'm returned to the shell prompt

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12073124)

Comment: @TobySpeight I disagree: it does provide the answer, which is: your installation of GDB is broken, you should work with your sysadmin to get it fixed; in the meantime you could try a different debugger.